# How could i pass parameter to pika callback

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I use pika to interact with RabbitMQ server as following:
1. P1 send message to RabbitMQ
2. C1 is an pyqt4 desktop tray application,which will show the above message once received.
The code is as following:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

import systray_rc


class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.createIconGroupBox()
        self.createMessageGroupBox()

        self.iconLabel.setMinimumWidth(self.durationLabel.sizeHint().width())

        self.createActions()
        self.createTrayIcon()

        self.showMessageButton.clicked.connect(self.showMessage)
        self.showIconCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.trayIcon.setVisible)
        self.iconComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setIcon)
        self.trayIcon.messageClicked.connect(self.messageClicked)
        self.trayIcon.activated.connect(self.iconActivated)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.iconGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.messageGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.iconComboBox.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.trayIcon.show()

        self.setWindowTitle("Systray")
        self.resize(400, 300)       



    def setVisible(self, visible):
        self.minimizeAction.setEnabled(visible)
        self.maximizeAction.setEnabled(not self.isMaximized())
        self.restoreAction.setEnabled(self.isMaximized() or not visible)
        super(Window, self).setVisible(visible)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.trayIcon.isVisible():
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Systray",
                    "The program will keep running in the system tray. To "
                    "terminate the program, choose <b>Quit</b> in the "
                    "context menu of the system tray entry.")
            self.hide()
            event.ignore()

    def setIcon(self, index):
        icon = self.iconComboBox.itemIcon(index)
        self.trayIcon.setIcon(icon)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)

        self.trayIcon.setToolTip(self.iconComboBox.itemText(index))

    def iconActivated(self, reason):
        if reason in (QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger, QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.DoubleClick):
            self.iconComboBox.setCurrentIndex(
                    (self.iconComboBox.currentIndex() + 1)
                    % self.iconComboBox.count())
        elif reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.MiddleClick:
            self.showMessage()

    def showMessage(self):
        icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.MessageIcon(
                self.typeComboBox.itemData(self.typeComboBox.currentIndex()))
#        self.trayIcon.showMessage(self.titleEdit.text(),
#                self.bodyEdit.toPlainText(), icon,
#                self.durationSpinBox.value() * 1000)
        self.trayIcon.showMessage('stock alarm',
                'test', icon,
                self.durationSpinBox.value() * 1000)

    def messageClicked(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, "Systray",
                "Sorry, I already gave what help I could.\nMaybe you should "
                "try asking a human?")

    def createIconGroupBox(self):
        self.iconGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Tray Icon")

        self.iconLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Icon:")

        self.iconComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/bad.svg'), "Bad")
        self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/heart.svg'), "Heart")
        self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/trash.svg'), "Trash")

        self.showIconCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox("Show icon")
        self.showIconCheckBox.setChecked(True)

        iconLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        iconLayout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)
        iconLayout.addWidget(self.iconComboBox)
        iconLayout.addStretch()
        iconLayout.addWidget(self.showIconCheckBox)
        self.iconGroupBox.setLayout(iconLayout)

    def createMessageGroupBox(self):
        self.messageGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Balloon Message")

        typeLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Type:")

        self.typeComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.typeComboBox.addItem("None", QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.NoIcon)
        self.typeComboBox.addItem(self.style().standardIcon(
                QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxInformation), "Information",
                QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Information)
        self.typeComboBox.addItem(self.style().standardIcon(
                QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning), "Warning",
                QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Warning)
        self.typeComboBox.addItem(self.style().standardIcon(
                QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxCritical), "Critical",
                QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Critical)
        self.typeComboBox.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.durationLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Duration:")

        self.durationSpinBox = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.durationSpinBox.setRange(5, 60)
        self.durationSpinBox.setSuffix(" s")
        self.durationSpinBox.setValue(15)

        durationWarningLabel = QtGui.QLabel("(some systems might ignore this "
                "hint)")
        durationWarningLabel.setIndent(10)

        titleLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Title:")

        self.titleEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit("Cannot connect to network")

        bodyLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Body:")

        self.bodyEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.bodyEdit.setPlainText("Don't believe me. Honestly, I don't have "
                "a clue.\nClick this balloon for details.")

        self.showMessageButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Message")
        self.showMessageButton.setDefault(True)

        messageLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        messageLayout.addWidget(typeLabel, 0, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.typeComboBox, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.durationLabel, 1, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.durationSpinBox, 1, 1)
        messageLayout.addWidget(durationWarningLabel, 1, 2, 1, 3)
        messageLayout.addWidget(titleLabel, 2, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.titleEdit, 2, 1, 1, 4)
        messageLayout.addWidget(bodyLabel, 3, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.bodyEdit, 3, 1, 2, 4)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.showMessageButton, 5, 4)
        messageLayout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
        messageLayout.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        self.messageGroupBox.setLayout(messageLayout)

    def createActions(self):
        self.minimizeAction = QtGui.QAction("Mi&nimize", self,
                triggered=self.hide)

        self.maximizeAction = QtGui.QAction("Ma&ximize", self,
                triggered=self.showMaximized)

        self.restoreAction = QtGui.QAction("&Restore", self,
                triggered=self.showNormal)

        self.quitAction = QtGui.QAction("&Quit", self,
                triggered=QtGui.qApp.quit)

    def createTrayIcon(self):
         self.trayIconMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.minimizeAction)
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.maximizeAction)
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.restoreAction)
         self.trayIconMenu.addSeparator()
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.quitAction)

         self.trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(self)
         self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.trayIconMenu)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print " [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body,)
        #window.showMessage = body
        #window.showMessage()
        #self.showMessage()

def subsribeRabbit():
    import pika
    import sys
    from util import settings

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=settings.RABBIT_SERVER))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=settings.STOCK_ALARMS_TOPIC,
                             type='topic')

    result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
    queue_name = result.method.queue

    binding_keys = '#'

    for binding_key in binding_keys:
        channel.queue_bind(exchange=settings.STOCK_ALARMS_TOPIC,
                           queue=queue_name,
                           routing_key=binding_key)

    print ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C'


    channel.basic_consume(callback,
                          queue=queue_name,
                          no_ack=True)

    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    from cron.realtimemonitorschedule import startMonitor    

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable():
        QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Systray",
                "I couldn't detect any system tray on this system.")
        sys.exit(1)

    QtGui.QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    window = Window()
    window.show()   
    from threading import Thread
    thread = Thread(target = subsribeRabbit)
    thread.start()
    #thread.join()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The question is that how could i call window.showMessage in the callback() function?Thanks in advance, i'm new to both Python and RabbitMQ.

Comment: Please trim down your code to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem. As it is now, people will have a hard time understanding your question and helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to define window for global variable as following:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

import systray_rc

window = Window()
window.show()  

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.createIconGroupBox()
        self.createMessageGroupBox()

        self.iconLabel.setMinimumWidth(self.durationLabel.sizeHint().width())

        self.createActions()
        self.createTrayIcon()

        self.showMessageButton.clicked.connect(self.showMessage)
        self.showIconCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.trayIcon.setVisible)
        self.iconComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setIcon)
        self.trayIcon.messageClicked.connect(self.messageClicked)
        self.trayIcon.activated.connect(self.iconActivated)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.iconGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.messageGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.iconComboBox.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.trayIcon.show()

        self.setWindowTitle("Systray")
        self.resize(400, 300)       



    def setVisible(self, visible):
        self.minimizeAction.setEnabled(visible)
        self.maximizeAction.setEnabled(not self.isMaximized())
        self.restoreAction.setEnabled(self.isMaximized() or not visible)
        super(Window, self).setVisible(visible)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.trayIcon.isVisible():
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Systray",
                    "The program will keep running in the system tray. To "
                    "terminate the program, choose <b>Quit</b> in the "
                    "context menu of the system tray entry.")
            self.hide()
            event.ignore()

    def setIcon(self, index):
        icon = self.iconComboBox.itemIcon(index)
        self.trayIcon.setIcon(icon)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)

        self.trayIcon.setToolTip(self.iconComboBox.itemText(index))

    def iconActivated(self, reason):
        if reason in (QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger, QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.DoubleClick):
            self.iconComboBox.setCurrentIndex(
                    (self.iconComboBox.currentIndex() + 1)
                    % self.iconComboBox.count())
        elif reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.MiddleClick:
            self.showMessage()

    def showMessage(self,text='test'):
        icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.MessageIcon(
                self.typeComboBox.itemData(self.typeComboBox.currentIndex()))
#        self.trayIcon.showMessage(self.titleEdit.text(),
#                self.bodyEdit.toPlainText(), icon,
#                self.durationSpinBox.value() * 1000)
        self.trayIcon.showMessage('stock alarm',
                'test', icon,
                self.durationSpinBox.value() * 1000)

    def messageClicked(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, "Systray",
                "Sorry, I already gave what help I could.\nMaybe you should "
                "try asking a human?")

    def createIconGroupBox(self):
        self.iconGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Tray Icon")

        self.iconLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Icon:")

        self.iconComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/bad.svg'), "Bad")
        self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/heart.svg'), "Heart")
        self.iconComboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/trash.svg'), "Trash")

        self.showIconCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox("Show icon")
        self.showIconCheckBox.setChecked(True)

        iconLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        iconLayout.addWidget(self.iconLabel)
        iconLayout.addWidget(self.iconComboBox)
        iconLayout.addStretch()
        iconLayout.addWidget(self.showIconCheckBox)
        self.iconGroupBox.setLayout(iconLayout)

    def createMessageGroupBox(self):
        self.messageGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox("Balloon Message")

        typeLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Type:")

        self.typeComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.typeComboBox.addItem("None", QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.NoIcon)
        self.typeComboBox.addItem(self.style().standardIcon(
                QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxInformation), "Information",
                QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Information)
        self.typeComboBox.addItem(self.style().standardIcon(
                QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxWarning), "Warning",
                QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Warning)
        self.typeComboBox.addItem(self.style().standardIcon(
                QtGui.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxCritical), "Critical",
                QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Critical)
        self.typeComboBox.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.durationLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Duration:")

        self.durationSpinBox = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.durationSpinBox.setRange(5, 60)
        self.durationSpinBox.setSuffix(" s")
        self.durationSpinBox.setValue(15)

        durationWarningLabel = QtGui.QLabel("(some systems might ignore this "
                "hint)")
        durationWarningLabel.setIndent(10)

        titleLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Title:")

        self.titleEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit("Cannot connect to network")

        bodyLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Body:")

        self.bodyEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.bodyEdit.setPlainText("Don't believe me. Honestly, I don't have "
                "a clue.\nClick this balloon for details.")

        self.showMessageButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Show Message")
        self.showMessageButton.setDefault(True)

        messageLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        messageLayout.addWidget(typeLabel, 0, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.typeComboBox, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.durationLabel, 1, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.durationSpinBox, 1, 1)
        messageLayout.addWidget(durationWarningLabel, 1, 2, 1, 3)
        messageLayout.addWidget(titleLabel, 2, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.titleEdit, 2, 1, 1, 4)
        messageLayout.addWidget(bodyLabel, 3, 0)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.bodyEdit, 3, 1, 2, 4)
        messageLayout.addWidget(self.showMessageButton, 5, 4)
        messageLayout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
        messageLayout.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        self.messageGroupBox.setLayout(messageLayout)

    def createActions(self):
        self.minimizeAction = QtGui.QAction("Mi&nimize", self,
                triggered=self.hide)

        self.maximizeAction = QtGui.QAction("Ma&ximize", self,
                triggered=self.showMaximized)

        self.restoreAction = QtGui.QAction("&Restore", self,
                triggered=self.showNormal)

        self.quitAction = QtGui.QAction("&Quit", self,
                triggered=QtGui.qApp.quit)

    def createTrayIcon(self):
         self.trayIconMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.minimizeAction)
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.maximizeAction)
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.restoreAction)
         self.trayIconMenu.addSeparator()
         self.trayIconMenu.addAction(self.quitAction)

         self.trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(self)
         self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(self.trayIconMenu)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print " [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body,)
        window.showMessage(body)


def subsribeRabbit():
    import pika
    import sys
    from util import settings

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=settings.RABBIT_SERVER))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=settings.STOCK_ALARMS_TOPIC,
                             type='topic')

    result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
    queue_name = result.method.queue

    binding_keys = '#'

    for binding_key in binding_keys:
        channel.queue_bind(exchange=settings.STOCK_ALARMS_TOPIC,
                           queue=queue_name,
                           routing_key=binding_key)

    print ' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C'


    channel.basic_consume(callback,
                          queue=queue_name,
                          no_ack=True)

    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    from cron.realtimemonitorschedule import startMonitor    

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable():
        QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Systray",
                "I couldn't detect any system tray on this system.")
        sys.exit(1)

    QtGui.QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)


    from threading import Thread
    thread = Thread(target = subsribeRabbit)
    thread.start()
    #thread.join()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6):

*Note: This answer is using python3 so the syntax may be slightly different than the answers from three years ago.*

A better answer is to wrap your callback in a lambda. Then you can pass whatever you want so long as it is accessible when you call `basic_consume`.

First change your callback to just take the stuff you are interested in. (You could also refactor this into a class and pass in `self`.)

```
def on_message(window, method, body):
    print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body), end="")
```

then to consume...

```
channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback=lambda ch, method, properties, body: on_message(window, method, body),
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare a class instance and then pass the class method as the pika consumer_callback:

```
callback = classObject(additional_paramters)

channel.basic_consume(callback.method,
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)
```

Maybe?

Comment: You are my god! This is genius